# How do i overwrite the typescript loader in Angular 6/7?

Tags: webpack, angular6, angular7, ts-loader, awesome-typescript-loader

I am trying to implement a custom webpack configuration for my Angular 7 application that overwrites the typescript loader so i can use a customerTransformer (see [ts-loader/getCustomTransformer](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#getcustomtransformers--program-program---before-transformerfactory-after-transformerfactory--) or [awesome-typescript-loader/getCustomTransformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-typescript-loader))
in the TypeScript compiler pipeline.

Since the command `ng eject` is not possible since Angular 6, i use the following approach https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21 to use a custom webpack configuration. I use this `extra-webpack.config.js`.

```
const methodOverloading = require("../../../built/transformer/method-overloading").methodOverloading;

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts/,
        loader: 'ts-loader', // or 'awesome-typescript-loader'
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          getCustomTransformers: (program) => ({
            before: [methodOverloading(program)]
          }),
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

When i run `npm run start` or `npm run build` it runs without errors and also executes the code from the customTransformer. But the final build does not include the transformations from the customTransformer.

I suspect, that Angular 6/7 uses a different way to compile its TypeScript. But i don't know what this way is (tried ts-loader and awesome-typescript-loader). Also i don't know where i can see the used webpack.config of Angular. This would help, because then i could use the exact same configuration as Angular for `extra-webpack.config.js`. How can i overwrite the typescript loader in Angular 6/7?

I also tried different [merge strategies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack), but this also failed.

Comment: Maybe this link can help you, especially the part with configuring the laoder:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-angular-7-a-complete-guide-9a23c879f471

Comment: Hi! Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: @LppEdd hi, did you find a way? :)
I am trying to do the same but the overwritting itself fails

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy hi! Unfortunately no, if I remember correctly. Sad

Comment: yeah, I am losing hope here too, thanks :)